# Error when switching user in mysql client

Tags: mysql

When trying to switch to another user from root I am getting the below error. But most of the examples show this is right syntax. Could you please help me?

> Error:
>   You have an error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u bcs_fms -p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute this command from CLI, not from the `mysql` console.

Comment: Ya its working fine now. Thanks a lot. And I have one more doubt that I am able to login to that user in mysql client in the server itself. But unable to login to mysql using the same username password from client machines (using workbench). What could be the solution?

Comment: [Permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql). Same user can have multiple passwords varying on the origin of the connection.